# MATLAB subplots empty spot when empty matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I want to show many subplots and if the matrix is empty it should show nothing. 
Now all subplots get the default image and no axes and text anymore. If I just comment the `imagesc` where I have my problem, then I get an ugly white plot with axes. Any suggestions? I don't want to write the whole code but that's my last imagecode:

```
      subplot(6,5,25)
      imagesc(image1{4,4})
       axis image;
      axis off;
      ylim=get(gca,'YLim');
      text(40,ylim(2),sprintf('S = %f  \nnumber in bin = %-10.3d',equal2(4,4), size(imagesS{4,4},3)'))
      colormap =[0:255;0:255;0:255]'/255;
       linkaxes();
```

Comment: arrange your code to put the display of each image in a loop. At the beginning of the loop, check if the matrix is empty. if not: display the image in a subplot, if yes: use `continue` to skip this loop iteration.

Comment: but each position of the subplots corresponds to a bin, so I need to show empty bins as well.